# ¿Cómo correr dos proyectos Laravel en un mismo VPS on subdominio?

Tags: laravel, apache, azure, dominio, centos7

tengo un servidor Centos 7, en el cual tengo un proyecto en Laravel corriendo con apache, en un subdominio tipo sub1.miurl.com.

Hasta ahí todo bien.
Ahora tengo otro proyecto laravel en mi mismo servidor, el cual necesito que quede asociado a otro subdominio, por ejemplo sub2.miurl.com.

Aquí estoy un poco perdido, ya que no sé como asociarlo desde apache en el httpd.conf o donde corresponda. 
He logrado hacer algo al llamar el segundo proyecto de Laravel desde otro puerto, algo así como sub1.miurl.com:8081, pero lo que necesito es llamarlo desde otro subdominio.

Los dominios los gestiono a través de Azure en una zona DNS.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Has creado los hosts en el httpd-vhost.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo te lo explicare agrandes rasgos.

primero tienes que hacer la carpeta de tu nuevo proyecto ejemplo yo las uso asi.

```
/home
   /proyecto1
   /proyecto2
   /proyectoN
```

Tienes que asegurarte que el grupo del servidor tenga permisos suficientes sobre el directorio.

Ahora lo que tienes que hacer es crearles un virtual host para que este te dirija hacia el directorio que quieras.

No recuerdo si en centOS esta en este directorio.

```
etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

tienes que crear un nuevo archivo como los que están en el directorio. Este es el archivo de configuración del virtual host.

Una vez que lo hayas echo. Solo lo tienes que agregar al servidor.

```
sudo a2ensite "nombre de tu virtual host"
```

Ya que lo hayas agregado solo tienes que reiniciar el servidor.

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Y listo cuando entres al dominio tus DNS redirigirá a tu VPS,
Cuando tu VPS reciba una solicitud la descriminara por la cabezara de la peticion.

"dominio1.com" -> /directorio1

"dominio2.com" -> /directorio2

Espero te sirva. 
Si necesitas mas orientación puedes googlear como implementar un virtual host en centOS

Saludos.

Comment: `a2ensite` es de debian, en centOS hay que crear los symlinks. la carpeta de configuración también cambia es `/etc/httpd/`, hay que crear las sites-available y sites-enabled y luego activar/incluir la de enableds en el httpd.conf con `Include sites-enabled/*.conf`